# map in reactjs is taking too much time to load

Tags: reactjs

so I was working with my code but then I realized that my map function is taking too much time to load, because there is array of 147783 elements that it has to go through, I wanted to know that how to show that this value is loading since chrome is showing error when its loading that page has gone unresponsive

Here is my code

```
export default class addGy extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          countries: Country.getAllCountries(),
          states: State.getAllStates(),
          cities: City.getAllCities()
        }
    }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          console.log(position)
          console.log("Latitude is :", position.coords.latitude);
          console.log("Longitude is :", position.coords.longitude);
        });
        /*console.log("Country:: "+Country.getAllCountries()[0].name);
        console.log("City:: "+City.getAllCities()[0].name);*/
        console.log(this.state.cities)
        
      }
      
    render() {
      
        return (
<Form>
  
<Row className="mb-3">
    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCity">
      <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control as="select" multiple>
      {//map function thats taking time to load UI component
        this.state.cities.map(ele=>{
          return (
          <option value={`${ele.name}`} className="d-inline mx-2 col-sm-5" onClick={({target}) => target.classList.toggle('bg-primary')}>
              {ele.name}
         </option>
          )
        })
      }
      </Form.Control>
    </Form.Group>
</Row>
            
  <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
    Submit
  </Button>
</Form>
        );
    }
  
}
```

Comment: You have a select with 147783 options. Performance is not the main issue here. What use is a select with that many options? Why are there that many options?

Comment: @Emil Karlsson I am trying to add all cities of world as option so that I can select any city I want or even multiple

Comment: I wouldn't do that with a <select>. Loading all of these into the DOM is just resource-intensive and UX unfriendly. Instead, consider an Autocomplete component.

Comment: what's an autocomplete component??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to do something like this:

```js
export default class addGy extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          loading: false
          countries: Country.getAllCountries(),
          states: State.getAllStates(),
          cities: City.getAllCities()
        }
    }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({loading: true})
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          console.log(position)
          console.log("Latitude is :", position.coords.latitude);
          console.log("Longitude is :", position.coords.longitude);
        });
        /*console.log("Country:: "+Country.getAllCountries()[0].name);
        console.log("City:: "+City.getAllCities()[0].name);*/
        console.log(this.state.cities)
        getAllCities().then((response) => this.setState({
          cities: response,
          loading: false
        }))
        
      }
      
    render() {
      
        return (
<Form>
  
<Row className="mb-3">
    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCity">
      <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control as="select" multiple>
      this.state.loading ? loading... : (
      {//map function thats taking time to load UI component
        this.state.cities.map(ele=>{
          return (
          <option value={`${ele.name}`} className="d-inline mx-2 col-sm-5" onClick={({target}) => target.classList.toggle('bg-primary')}>
              {ele.name}
         </option>
          )
        })
      })
      </Form.Control>
    </Form.Group>
</Row>
            
  <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
    Submit
  </Button>
</Form>
        );
    }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The thing is to add a loading state and set it to true at the component did mount, an after calling get cities, turn it to false in reponse